# Replicate UIScrollView's scrollToTop does not expand the UINavigationBar on UITabBar tap in iOS 11

Tags: uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11, uitabbar

(Similar to this question, which is unanswered: [Tableview scroll to top not going all the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178880/tableview-scroll-to-top-not-going-all-the-way), as well as this one, also unanswered: [Show navigation bar's large title and search bar on scroll to top collection view iOS 11 Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258217/show-navigation-bars-large-title-and-search-bar-on-scroll-to-top-collection-vie))

I am trying to replicate scrolling to the top of a UITableView on status bar tap, but when I've tapped the UITabBar item and I'm already in that view. I have the tapping part working, but the scrolling to top is not working as I want it to.

The `tableview` is embedded in a `navigationbar` with large titles, and the `searchbar` is in the header, so it expands and collapses with scroll (the default behavior).

I am using the following to scroll, which, as expected, scrolls to the first table view cell, not expanding the navigation bar and/or the search bar:

```
[tv scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

I can't seem to figure out how to scroll to the top and expand the navigation bar and the search bar. Manually calculating the content offset of the `tableview` doesn't work, as the offsets of the `tableview` are obviously different when the `tableview` is scrolled. Furthermore, I can't store the offset, as different screen sizes have different content offsets for an expanded `navigationbar` and `searchbar`.

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm a bit late to the action here but for future reference:

For iOS 10+ (sufficient, since growing navigationBars were introduced in 11) you can use

```
scrollView.perform(NSSelectorFromString("_scrollToTopIfPossible:"), with: true)
```

This is **private API**. I've searched for a couple of hours and tried a lot of stuff but in the end this is the only thing that worked. Note that WhatsApp seems to be using the same method. Maybe they have a special deal with Apple or hide the api call (*cough* base64 *cough*).

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UIWindow (SCROLL)

- (void)performScrollToTop {

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_scrollToTopViewsUnderScreenPointIfNecessary:resultHandler:");

    if ([self respondsToSelector:selector] == false) {
        return;
    }

    NSMethodSignature *signature = [UIWindow instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];

    if (signature == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[UIWindow instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];

    [invocation setTarget:self];

    [invocation setSelector:selector];

    CGRect statusBarFrame = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame;

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(statusBarFrame.size.width / 2.0, statusBarFrame.size.height + 1.0);

    [invocation setArgument:&point atIndex:2];

    [invocation invoke];
}

@end
```

Comment: When giving an answer, please elaborate on why this is the right answer.